# Angular 7 multiple library dependencies

Tags: angular

I am making a shared project in Angular 7 with many libraries. When I have a dependency between 2 libraries, I get this error

```
BUILD ERROR
Could not resolve entry (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\dist\icons\esm2015\my.library.workflows-icons.js)
Error: Could not resolve entry (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\dist\icons\esm2015\my.library.workflows-icons.js)
    at error (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:3460:30)
    at C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:21474:17

Could not resolve entry (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\dist\icons\esm2015\my.library.workflows-icons.js)
Error: Could not resolve entry (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\dist\icons\esm2015\my.library.workflows-icons.js)
    at error (C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:3460:30)
    at C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:21474:17
```

I tried all kind of things. One of them being add paths to tsconfig.lib.json file, in the library where I have a dependency. 
But the error continues

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issues and spent couple of hours to figure out solution. Finally I made following changes to resolve the issue
Assume library2 is depend on library1

- Use relative path import model in same library
  When use VSCode, some time it will auto import module on auto fix and the path is

```
   import { something } from 'libary2/lib/models'
```

it should be changed to

```
   import { something } from '../../models';
```

- add built version of library1 to the path of library2's tsconfig.lib.json, also need specify the baseUrl

```
 "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir": "./out-tsc/lib",
     "baseUrl": "./",
     ....
     "paths": {
       "library1": ["../../dist/library1"],
       "library1/*": ["../../dist/library1/*"],
     }
 }
```